# how to set style in javascript to a url link when this page load

Tags: twig

I have a admin panel and agent panel,I want to hide the sidebar in agent panel first then i used this code

```
{% block body_header %}
    {% if data.username == 'client' %}
        {% include 'block/menu.twig' with {'menu': data.main_menu} %}
    {% else %}
        {% include 'block/menu.twig' with {'menu': data.main_menu} %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

if username of the login form is client then `display:none` otherwise `display:bock` so there is an error init that if any other login like master then the sidebar shows there

I need to hide on the `agentpanel.php?redirect=dashboard.php` link when this url loads

Comment: I'm not perfectly sure to understand the question, but if you are willing to hide an element based on a server side condition, you may just add a css rule on the twig only when such condition is met. I can't suggest the css rule because is not clear the selector to discriminate such element

Comment: The code you provided in combination with your question make little sense.. How are we supposed to help you?

Comment: Please post the error you are receiving, but from what I can tell you would need to surround your current code with an extra check to test if `data.username` is actually set and isn't empty or change the `{% else %}` to `{% elseif data.username == 'admin' %}`